# Is there any research showing whether relative or absolute times are easier for humans to read?

Tags: user-behavior, time, timeline

I would like to know about the time format which is used by Facebook - relative times such as "2 hours ago", rather than absolute times such as "13:35".

Is there any research about which time format is easier to read for humans and why?

[image: time]

Comment: Note how you can tell on the right which article came first, while on the left you can not. There can be situations where this is important.

Comment: Whatever you do, *please* don't make the ridiculously common mistake of generating sentences like "Lee posted this in 2 minutes time"; it's very rare to actually need relative past and relative future on the same field, so always use something like "just now" or "in a moment" if the calculation is out of range.

Comment: Just in case someone decides, on their app, to add a fuller date, please, please, please : use the [international iso8601 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) :  In full: YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss+hh:mm (ex: 2017-11-12T21:12:01+05:00, if you need timezone too). Please don't invent 'yet another date format' with all their ambiguity and "non-standard"-ness. There are shortened versions as well (see the link). Keep the ':' between times, please (the 'T' is really usefull in logs, and arguably less so in a human context, but I'd still keep it to get it to be more known and used globally).

Comment: My personal experience is that I have difficulties with relative times. I find myself calculating the absolute time in my head, which might not be as easy as it should (e.g. when it says "17 hours ago" and I read it in the morning). If you use them, please provide a setting to use absolute times instead.

Comment: Just please allow for some way to obtain the **actual** time a document was posted/generated.  Even if you have to hover for alt text or tap to toggle between the formats, it is always so frustrating to see a bunch of documents with the same relative time and no way to discern reading order.

Comment: How do you propose to define "easier to read" and test it in a study?

Comment: I wonder if facebook wants this to be easy?

Comment: Random factoid: The easiest time format for humans to read is ***The Clockface***... which is fine on an areoplane dashboard, but perhaps not so convenient on a facebook post.

Comment: @OlivierDulac That is a serialisation format that is meant to be 1) accurate and 2) unambiguous, but it's not meant to be easily readable by humans.

Comment: @OlivierDulac Agreed with Mr Lister; at minimum, for human-readability, replace `T` with a space and add a space before `+`.  The gaps create a legible-at-able-glance group of 3 things: Date, Time, Timezone.  The ISO standard is one big blob that takes a moment to understand.

Comment: @OlivierDulac - Except the end of that stamp is an _offset_, not a timezone (especially as most people use it).  First, I would be surprised if most people actually knew what their offset was.  Second, in many cases their timezone will change its offset, and most people forget when that event occurs.  If a user sees a time, they're going to assume it's "local" to them, even if the situation doesn't warrant it (eg, checking email while on vacation may show the time for your "home" zone).

Comment: @JimmyBreck-McKye Everyone's design stands or falls on a zillion little differences. And I'd be very surprised if nobody's ever run a study on this, especially big web companies like Facebook and Google who make almost all their popularity from their design!

Comment: I personally don't mind "2 minutes ago" but I hate "8 months ago". If the date matters, then I want to compare it with other events ("was that before or after he left Acme corp?") . As for the question, the answer to usability questions like this depends almost entirely on how you select your sample and what questions you ask them.

Comment: Incidentally, "2 minutes ago" can be justified on the grounds that it's independent of timezone. "Yesterday" can't. Your yesterday is not my yesterday.

Answer (score 77):

You could also show both formats: 13:35 (2 hours ago)
This way the user could figure out either one easily, depending on what they wanted. You could also allow searching/filtering by either.

Comment: Similar to this, StackExchange shows the absolute time on hover

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks for the notice, @Izkata

Comment: Didn't notice it either. Wouldn't recommend it as a solution if users never notice it.

Comment: @Izkata this seems to be a widely-supported feature. Another example is GitHub, and I'm sure to have seen this on many other sites.

Comment: @EdmundReed perhaps you never felt the _need_ to know the exact time of a post. I've wanted to know which was two answer was first a number of times, and hovering over the rough-relative information seemed quite an obvious first attempt. OTOH, it never gets in the way when you don't need the exact time info (which is very common). So I'd say, a hover-tooltip is an excellent solution.

Comment: @leftaroundabout this is a very good point

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Hiding the absolute time in a hover tooltip *may* be acceptable if you also use CSS media styling to display absolute time when printing.  Generating archival versions of the content with times formatted relative to the moment the archive was created is insane.

Comment: @BenVoigt why would anybody [print out web pages](https://what-if.xkcd.com/59/)?

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Why do you assume I mean printing "out" (dead tree paper) vs printing to file (e.g. PDF)?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question (Is there any research...)

Comment: Please! I wish people did this! `2017-09-21 16:10 (2 hours ago)`

Comment: Also - after two days ago it shows absolute (UTC) times.

Answer (score 59):

I'm not sure about hard research, but there's a good article from UX Movement:

**[Absolute vs. Relative Timestamps](http://uxmovement.com/content/absolute-vs-relative-timestamps-when-to-use-which/)**

**When to use absolute timestamps:**

> There are times when users need to look back on past content to retrieve information. Without absolute timestamps, users can’t target a specific period to find the information.
>
> Sites that host photos, documents, messages, tasks and events all need absolute timestamps. These content will hold utility in the future when users need to reference them. Use absolute timestamps when users can go back and make use of past content.

**When to use relative timestamps:**

> Accuracy isn’t important with relative timestamps, but immediacy is. When users want to know how long ago a site published a post, they prefer time units in written form. This way they don’t have to mentally calculate dates and times and count back from the present day.
>
> Not only that, but users don’t have to convert time zones with relative timestamps. Content published an hour ago or five hours ago makes no difference to users who only need a general sense of recency.

Comment: _"If your site content updates often, or has a lot of user activity, you should use relative timestamps. Sites that publish news, or have forums where users post links and comments need to show immediacy. This allows users to stay up-to-date with new information as it comes in."_ Is this widely accepted? *Especially* with news on ongoing events, I'd like to be able to relate the timestamp of the news *by minute* to the event and other news sources, I don't see how I could even do that with relative timestamps.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually addresses the question of 'is there any research'.

Comment: Pity the author of that article doesn't cite his sources or studies. It just reads like an opinion piece.

Answer (score 10):

When you use absolute timestamps, you need to find out which timezone the user is in. This can be a guess based on IP address (which may be wrong) or a setting in the user profile (which needs to be filled out during user signup, adding another field), or a mix between both.

It is confusing to the user when you get it wrong. When I travel abroad, some websites show timestamps in my home timezone and others use the one where I currently am. The daylight savings switch in autumn will also show timestamps between 2AM and 3AM seemingly out of order, or imply that only a few minutes passed between two entries, when it was really an hour.

StackOverflow shows relative time for recent posts and switches to absolute (date only) after some time, when no one cares about the time of day a post was made anymore. What is best for your website depends on your application, whether there will be access to old material, whether users need to follow nonlinear reply chains, ...

Comment: Or just give the timestamp in UTC, and let the user decide if they want to use a TZ offset or not.

Comment: @MontyHarder, that is okay for people living in the UK about half the time. Specifically, the half that is in winter.

Comment: If you format it in the browser, that browser usually knows the time zone of the computer (which often is the same as the user's one).

Comment: @MontyHarder Go out on the street, grab the first 10 people you find and ask them in which timezone they are. I'd be surprised if you got more than 60-70% correct answers (and that's probably overly optimistic).

Comment: @MontyHarder UTC seems to be hard for many people. Again and again I encounter people/websites who think UTC is "the time in the UK". Which of course it is only when DST isn't in effect (less than half a year).

Answer (score 8):

The choice between absolute (13:35) and relative (2 hours ago) is made depending on the type of content you're browsing. Absolute timestamps are used when your user needs to reference something; sites that host photos, documents, messages, tasks and events all need absolute timestamps. You need to know the exact date something was published, it's not important to know how long ago that was from where you are now.

Relative timestamps are more emotion oriented; when your site content updates often, or has a lot of user activity, you use relative timestamps. This is important because you are trying to see whether or not something is new compared to where you are now. A stamp saying 2 hours ago is much faster at telling you this is fresh content. You don't have to mentally calculate dates and times and count back from the current time. This also avoids the whole timezone issue.

Source: http://uxmovement.com/content/absolute-vs-relative-timestamps-when-to-use-which/